# how to trace a file by the route url

Tags: urls, routing

i want to know, how can i zero in on the file that is rendered for a prticular route url.
I am using the postname permalinks i.e. `https://domainname.com/sample-post/`

How can i check the file that is getting rendered for this route like `domain.com/abc/def` ?

TIA

Comment: this is not a duplicate of the above link, I am trying to get the page that is rendered through the route url.

Comment: I have a site than is rendering contents for domain.com/product/customization-tool.
i want to find out where can i get this contents and templates that are renderered for this url?